# how to password protect some application in ubuntu

Tags: community, productivity

- I have read other answers regarding this , they are telling to create a seperate user account
- but what i want is that
  I want to restrict myself from using some application.
- Like there is blocker hero , app locker apps for android , is there any application for ubuntu that can provide me functionalities that these app lock type apps provide.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> I have read other answers regarding this , they are telling to create a seperate user account

That only works for users that are not an admin user or that do not own the system.

> but what i want is that I want to restrict myself from using some application. Is there any application for ubuntu that can provide me functionalities that these app lock type apps provide.

No. As the owner of a machine you can block whatever you want and however you want but you can always circumvent what you did.

Even if you uninstall the application and then mutulate your system by removing `apt`, `dpkg` and any other tool to install software  even then rebooting into a live session would circumvent that. Even forgetten your admin password can be fixed when you have physical access to your machine.

You need to learn to restrain yourself from using that application.

> Like there is blocker hero , app locker apps for android

Same rules apply here: you do not own your Android. It is vendor locked. If you do own it (aka. "root" it) you can disable and circumvent Blocler Hero regardless what you blocked.

For this to work you need a 2nd person who you make admin and sets you up as a normal user. He/she then sets an admin password and blocks whatever you want to block.

That still means that when you have physical access to a system nothing can stop you from doing what you want. Including reverting any block.
Simply not possible using an operating system (not just Ubuntu): an admin user on an operating system has all the privileges to admin a system. And having physical access to a machine means you own it and can do anything with it.

Comment: your answer seems good theoretically, but not practical

Answer (score 1):

It is simply not possible for you to do what you're asking to be done. If it's your computer, you can do whatever you want with it, so if you uninstall a program you can simply reinstall it. And if it's not your computer, you can't remove programs from it. (You could ask your system administrator.)

That said, it's possible that all you really need is to make it more difficult to get to the program you're finding overly compelling. Assuming you have administrator rights to the computer you're using **and** that there are times when you **do** want to use that program:

- Find the `.desktop` file  that allows you to launch the application from the GUI and disable it somehow. Do the same for the executable itself. Best would be to remove the executable permission from it; that way, when you learn to control yourself, you can re-enable it easily. Or;
- Alias the command to something annoying, like this:

```bash
alias <command>='echo "GET BACK TO WORK!" | figlet'
```

I suppose if you wanted to disable the command between, for example, the hours of 9am and 5pm, a bash script could do the job.